# drop-down ul only expands to first child li

Tags: css

This is a very simple straight forward css drop-down nav menu.

Unfortunately the drop-down ul with the background gradient will only expand to the height of the first list item.
I've written this same css for other sites and for some reason it's not working on this one. Can't figure it out for the life of me. If anyone has any idea what might be going on I'd be really grateful!

Here's a link:

http://madzecreations.com/_test_site/

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any errors or something others.... it expands on all li's pls clear your cache

Comment: no issue for me..can u explain more?

Comment: Is there a reason you have `max-height` defined for your `li` elements multiple times? If those aren't necessary, just remove those and your problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` element contains 4  `<a>`  elements - yet you have a rule `max-height: 30px;`

change that to `max-height: 180px;` and it should work.

```
#main_nav li:hover > ul li {

max-height: 180px;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
position: relative;
z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: This would have worked except that I wanted to take advantage of css transitions and have the list items accordion with the drop-down. And without the links in their own li tags it only transitioned the opacity. It was really just a silly html error. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You have added the gradient in  instead you can add in li a:

Instead of here:

```
#main_nav li ul{
linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCBB07 0%, #EFE39E 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
}
```

put the gradient here:

```
#main_nav li ul li a{
linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCBB07 0%, #EFE39E 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out it was just an html error; I just didn't tag each drop-down link in it's own li tag:

I did this:

```
    <li>
    <a href="#">NAV 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">FIRST LI</a>
    <a href="#">SECOND LI</a>
    <a href="#">THIRD LI</a>
    <a href="#">FOURTH LI</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

I should have done this:

```
    <li>
    <a href="#">NAV 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">FIRST LI</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">SECOND LI</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">THIRD LI</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">FOURTH LI</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

Works perfectly now of course.  Thanks for everyone's help though, I appreciate it!